# New project doesn't cout any values?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 6160;
    int b = 6160;
    int c = a + b;
    int d = 0;
    int f = 100;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= c; i++)
    {
        while (c >= f)
        {
            d += 1;
            c = c - f;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << d << "-" << c;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This program is supposed to increase `d` by 1 each time `c` reaches `100` and then start counting again till it's `100` and then increase `d` by 1 more and if there is any extra numbers that didn't reach `100` after the whole calculation is done the this will be `c` .. the matter is when I put these values in the program above in `a` and `b` I get this answer:

```
122-120
```

while it should be:

```
123-20
```

Comment: What programm do you use to compile code?

Comment: Add a `cout.flush();` before `system("pause");`.

Comment: i used     cout.flush(); but didn't work :| !

Comment: that `while` could just as well be an `if`

Comment: @Jefffrey when i used if the result was 1-12220 :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove your for loop and the `break` in the while loop: http://ideone.com/WlL2JN

```
int main()
{
    const int a = 6160;
    const int b = 6160;
    int c = a + b;
    int d = 0;
    const int f = 100;

    while (c >= f) {
        d += 1;
        c = c - f;
    }
    std::cout << d << "-" << c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

BTW, you may do directly:

```
d = c / f;
c = c % f;
```